# Is there a way to pass current BUILD_NUMBER to Gradle deamon from Jenkins build?

Tags: jenkins, gradle, environment-variables, daemon

I am accessing Jenkins build number in Gradle script by calling:

```
def buildNumber = System..getenv('BUILD_NUMBER')
```

It works fine the first time I run the build. The second time the build is run, the number is not incremented, it stays the same from previous build run.
I am using 4.4.1 version of Gradle. I don't remember having the same problem with earlier versions.

My current workaround is to pass --no-daemon switch to Gradle. However, that way I am not able to benefit from daemon feature. Is there a way to use daemons ans still get the correct build number in Gradle build?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you using Java 9? With Java 9 it is not possible for Gradle anymore to modify the environment of the Daemon - so you cannot pass properties by using environment variables.
You should see the following warning in your logs:

```
Warning: Unable able to set daemon's environment variables to match the client because: 
Java 9 does not support modifying environment variables.
```

You can pass the `'BUILD_NUMBER'` as a system property (`-DbuildNumber=$BUILD_NUMBER`) or a Gradle project property (`-PbuildNumber=$BUILD_NUMBER`) from by the command line of Gradle instead.

Comment: The environment variable problem with Java 9 was fixed in Gradle 4.10: https://docs.gradle.org/4.10/release-notes.html#environment-variables-kept-up-to-date-on-java-9+

Answer (score 2):

It seems this was discussed and solved [in the gradle forums](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-2-12-upto-gradle-3-5-problem-of-gradle-daemon-with-environment-variables-just-tested-on-windows-7-testcases-gradle-and-batch-files-are-added/22338/7), by reading the System env in a special block:

```
class Globals {
  String buildNr =  System.getenv( 'BUILD_NUMBER' ).toString()
}
ext {
   globals = new Globals()
}

// reference it like:
println "value of BUILD_NUMBER = " + globals.buildNr
```

Answer (score 0):

I normally build a key-value store with a timestamp using redis to store build numbers. This way i can isolate and retrieve , and send data back forth between any client.